# Closing a type of dropdown when one of the same type is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new with jQuery and javascript, and I need help with something...

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .active-dropdown').on("click", function (e) {
      $(this).next('ul').toggle();
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}

.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}

  .arrow-up {
    margin: 4px;
    float: right;
  }

  #active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #080808;
  }

  .clickCursor {
    cursor: pointer !important;
  }

  a.btn.btn-lg.btn-warning.errorright {
    margin-left: 300px;
    width: 255px;
  }

  a.btn.btn-lg.btn-warning.errorleft {
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: -117px;
  }

  .carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      text-align: left;
    }

    p.left{
      text-align: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    p.right{
      text-align: right;
    }

    h2.featurette-heading.trends{
      margin-top: -40px;
    }

    a.scroll.no-decoration:hover,
    a.scroll.no-decoration:active,
    a.scroll.no-decoration:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #337ab7;
    }

    .all-width {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .dropdown-toggle {
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu {
      position: relative;
  }
  
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      margin-top: -1px;
  }

    .nav>li>a {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

  <title>Pixel Pro | Tudo sobre jogos</title>

  <!-- BS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- FA -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Custom style and JS for this template -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Scripts -->

  <!-- Smooth Scroll -->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Add smooth scrolling to all links
      $("a.scroll").on('click', function (event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function () {


          });
        } // End if
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a id="pagetop"></a>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="active" href="/">Pixel Pro</a></li>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <!-- Dropdown without any subdropdowns
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sobre [Test] <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Indie <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#">Minecraft</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terraria</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">FPS <i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</a></li>
              </ul>
            -->

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sobre <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Indie <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Minecraft <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Terraria <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">FPS <i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Counter Strike: Global Offensive <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

            </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- A third dropdown (which isn't necessary in this dropdown)
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                          <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      -->
          </ul>
          </li>
          </ul>

          </li>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>



  </header>

  <main>
    <div id="GamesCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- To stop the automatic carousel, remove data-ride="carousel" -->
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#GamesCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#GamesCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#GamesCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Minecraft</h1>
              <p>Minecraft é um jogo de construção de sandbox criado pela Mojang AB, fundada por Markus Persson (Notch). A jogabilidade
                envolve jogadores que interagem com o mundo do jogo colocando e quebrando vários tipos de blocos em um ambiente
                tridimensional.
              </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning all-width" href="/subjects/minecraft/index.html" role="button">Saber mais</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Terraria</h1>
              <p>Começa por construir abrigos básicos, encontra e pega minérios e outros recursos. Descobre e cria até 300 armas
                de variedades mágicas, variadas e de corpo a corpo, bem como armaduras, e usa-as para combater centenas de
                inimigos diferentes. Em breve, estarás a ir frente a frente com qualquer dúzia de chefes enormes.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning all-width" href="/subjects/terraria/index.html" role="button">Saber mais</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Counter Strike: Global Offensive</h1>
              <p>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS:GO) é um jogo de tiro em primeira pessoa online desenvolvido pela Valve
                Corporation e pela Hidden Path Entertainment, sendo uma sequência de Counter-Strike: Source. É o quarto título
                principal da franquia.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning all-width" href="/subjects/csgo/index.html" role="button">Saber mais</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#GamesCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#GamesCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container marketing">
      <h2 class="featurette-heading trends">Melhores <span class="text-muted">tópicos</span></h2>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/minecraft_index.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2 class="left">Minecraft</h2>
          <p class="left">Minecraft é um jogo de construção de sandbox criado pela Mojang AB, fundada por Markus Persson (Notch). A jogabilidade
            envolve jogadores que interagem com o mundo do jogo colocando e quebrando vários tipos de blocos em um ambiente
            tridimensional.
          </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/subjects/minecraft/index.html" role="button">Saber Mais</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/terraria_index.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2 class="left">Terraria</h2>
          <p class="left">Começa por construir abrigos básicos, encontra e pega minérios e outros recursos. Descobre e cria até 300 armas
            de variedades mágicas, variadas e de corpo a corpo, bem como armaduras, e usa-as para combater centenas de inimigos
            diferentes. Em breve, estarás a ir frente a frente com qualquer dúzia de chefes enormes.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/subjects/terraria/index.html" role="button">Saber Mais</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <img class="img-circle" src="img/csgo_index.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
          <h2 class="left">Counter Strike: Global Offensive</h2>
          <p class="left">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS:GO) é um jogo de tiro em primeira pessoa online desenvolvido pela Valve Corporation
            e pela Hidden Path Entertainment, sendo uma sequência de Counter-Strike: Source. É o quarto título principal
            da franquia.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/subjects/csgo/index.html" role="button">Saber Mais</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Porque deves escolher-<span class="text-muted">nos?</span></h2>
          <p class="lead">Nós estamos a desenvolver um website muito elegante e moderno sem nenhum anúncio e feito com muito amor com toda
            a informação precisa e necessária, no entanto, temos apenas Minecraft, Terraria e CS: GO por enquanto.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="/img/heart.gif" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Qual o <span class="text-muted">conteúdo</span> atual?</h2>
          <p class="lead">Por agora, temos 3 matérias: Minecraft, Terraria, e CS:GO.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block img-circle" src="/img/game.gif" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <div class="row featurette">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="featurette-heading">Quem é o <span class="text-muted">dono</span> deste website?</h2>
          <p class="lead">O dono deste website chama-se Pedro, e é do sexo masculino. Este curte jogar jogos e também percebe um bocadinho
            de programação, então, decidiu criar este website para ajudar todos os gamers e jogadores.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block img-circle" src="img/ExplodingPedro.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer>
        <hr class="featurette-divider">
        <a href="#pagetop" class="scroll no-decoration"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i><p class="pull-right">Voltar para o topo</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2017 Pedro Ferreira &middot;</p>
      </footer>
  </main>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I want to, when someone clicks a dropdown submenu Topic, everything keep how it is, but, when someone clicks in ANOTHER dropdown submenu, all the others dropdown submenu should disappear.
If you got an answer tell me, please, I really need help.

-- EDIT --

I also need help in another thing, but that thing is also a problem with scripting and it has to see with the dropdown sub-menu, so I'll just edit here.

I want to, when someone clicks any of the  that shows a sub dropdown (a.active-dropdown), if the sub dropdown IS ALREADY visible, to it become invisible.

Comment: Thanks so much, this solved everything! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code so that it contains mostly just the layout of it and not much extraneous page content. Then in the JavaScript section, you'll see that I added the following line of code:

```
$(this).closest('nav').find('.dropdown-submenu > ul').hide();
```

This finds any dropdown submenus and hides them before opening the one you clicked on.

I added this as the first line of the click event handler, since it needs to hide open ones before opening a new one, otherwise it would open the menu then hide it immediately.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-submenu .active-dropdown').click(function(e){
        $(this).closest('nav').find('.dropdown-submenu > ul').hide();
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
    width: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-wrapper .container {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}

.dropdown-toggle {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.nav > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- BS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FA -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-bars" style="color:#fff;"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" id="active" href="#">Pixel Pro</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sobre <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Indie <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Minecraft <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Terraria <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">FPS <i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Counter Strike: Global Offensive <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before this line:

```
$(this).next('ul').toggle();
```

you can add:

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').find('ul').hide();
```

in order to close all the other dropdown.

The snippet:

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu .active-dropdown').on("click", function (e) {
    //
    // added next line
    //
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').find('ul').hide();
    
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
$("a.scroll").on('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function () {


        });
    } // End if
});
```

```css
body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    color: #5a5a5a;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}

.navbar-wrapper > .container {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
    width: auto;
}

.carousel {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.marketing .col-lg-4 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.marketing h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.featurette-divider {
    margin: 80px 0;
}

.featurette-heading {
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Navbar positioning foo */
    .navbar-wrapper .container {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    .carousel-caption p {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }

    .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .featurette-heading {
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
}

.arrow-up {
    margin: 4px;
    float: right;
}

#active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #080808;
}

.clickCursor {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

a.btn.btn-lg.btn-warning.errorright {
    margin-left: 300px;
    width: 255px;
}

a.btn.btn-lg.btn-warning.errorleft {
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: -117px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    text-align: left;
}

p.left {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

p.right {
    text-align: right;
}

h2.featurette-heading.trends {
    margin-top: -40px;
}

a.scroll.no-decoration:hover,
a.scroll.no-decoration:active,
a.scroll.no-decoration:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #337ab7;
}

.all-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.nav > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<header>
    <a id="pagetop"></a>

    <div class="navbar-wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                        aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" id="active" href="/">Pixel Pro</a></li>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <!-- Dropdown without any subdropdowns
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sobre [Test] <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Indie <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Minecraft</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terraria</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">FPS <i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    -->

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                           aria-expanded="false">Sobre <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Indie <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Minecraft <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Terraria <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">FPS <i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Counter Strike: Global Offensive <span
                                        class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Topic 6</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- A third dropdown (which isn't necessary in this dropdown)
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                              <a class="clickCursor active-dropdown">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          -->
                </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>

                </li>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>


</header>

<main>
    <div id="GamesCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- To stop the automatic carousel, remove data-ride="carousel" -->
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#GamesCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#GamesCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#GamesCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img class="first-slide"
                     src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                     alt="First slide">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Minecraft</h1>
                        <p>Minecraft é um jogo de construção de sandbox criado pela Mojang AB, fundada por Markus
                            Persson (Notch). A jogabilidade
                            envolve jogadores que interagem com o mundo do jogo colocando e quebrando vários tipos de
                            blocos em um ambiente
                            tridimensional.
                        </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning all-width" href="/subjects/minecraft/index.html"
                              role="button">Saber mais</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="second-slide"
                     src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                     alt="Second slide">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Terraria</h1>

                        <p>Começa por construir abrigos básicos, encontra e pega minérios e outros recursos. Descobre e
                            cria até 300 armas
                            de variedades mágicas, variadas e de corpo a corpo, bem como armaduras, e usa-as para
                            combater centenas de
                            inimigos diferentes. Em breve, estarás a ir frente a frente com qualquer dúzia de chefes
                            enormes.</p>

                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning all-width" href="/subjects/terraria/index.html"
                              role="button">Saber mais</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img class="third-slide"
                     src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
                     alt="Third slide">

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Counter Strike: Global Offensive</h1>

                        <p>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS:GO) é um jogo de tiro em primeira pessoa online
                            desenvolvido pela Valve
                            Corporation e pela Hidden Path Entertainment, sendo uma sequência de Counter-Strike: Source.
                            É o quarto título
                            principal da franquia.</p>

                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-warning all-width" href="/subjects/csgo/index.html" role="button">Saber
                            mais</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#GamesCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#GamesCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="container marketing">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading trends">Melhores <span class="text-muted">tópicos</span></h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="img-circle" src="img/minecraft_index.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140"
                     height="140">
                <h2 class="left">Minecraft</h2>
                <p class="left">Minecraft é um jogo de construção de sandbox criado pela Mojang AB, fundada por Markus
                    Persson (Notch). A jogabilidade
                    envolve jogadores que interagem com o mundo do jogo colocando e quebrando vários tipos de blocos em
                    um ambiente
                    tridimensional.
                </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/subjects/minecraft/index.html" role="button">Saber Mais</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="img-circle" src="img/terraria_index.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140"
                     height="140">
                <h2 class="left">Terraria</h2>
                <p class="left">Começa por construir abrigos básicos, encontra e pega minérios e outros recursos.
                    Descobre e cria até 300 armas
                    de variedades mágicas, variadas e de corpo a corpo, bem como armaduras, e usa-as para combater
                    centenas de inimigos
                    diferentes. Em breve, estarás a ir frente a frente com qualquer dúzia de chefes enormes.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/subjects/terraria/index.html" role="button">Saber Mais</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="img-circle" src="img/csgo_index.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140"
                     height="140">

                <h2 class="left">Counter Strike: Global Offensive</h2>

                <p class="left">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CS:GO) é um jogo de tiro em primeira pessoa online
                    desenvolvido pela Valve Corporation
                    e pela Hidden Path Entertainment, sendo uma sequência de Counter-Strike: Source. É o quarto título
                    principal
                    da franquia.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/subjects/csgo/index.html" role="button">Saber Mais</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="featurette-divider">
        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Porque deves escolher-<span class="text-muted">nos?</span></h2>

                <p class="lead">Nós estamos a desenvolver um website muito elegante e moderno sem nenhum anúncio e feito
                    com muito amor com toda
                    a informação precisa e necessária, no entanto, temos apenas Minecraft, Terraria e CS: GO por
                    enquanto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block" src="/img/heart.gif"
                     alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="featurette-divider">
        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-5">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Qual o <span class="text-muted">conteúdo</span> atual?</h2>

                <p class="lead">Por agora, temos 3 matérias: Minecraft, Terraria, e CS:GO.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-pull-7">
                <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block img-circle" src="/img/game.gif"
                     alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="featurette-divider">
        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Quem é o <span class="text-muted">dono</span> deste website?</h2>

                <p class="lead">O dono deste website chama-se Pedro, e é do sexo masculino. Este curte jogar jogos e
                    também percebe um bocadinho
                    de programação, então, decidiu criar este website para ajudar todos os gamers e jogadores.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img class="featurette-image img-responsive center-block img-circle" src="img/ExplodingPedro.jpg"
                     alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <hr class="featurette-divider">
            <a href="#pagetop" class="scroll no-decoration"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up arrow-up"
                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <p class="pull-right">Voltar para o topo</a></p>
            <p>&copy; 2017 Pedro Ferreira &middot;</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</main>
</div>
```

Comment: I also tested your code, and it worked just fine, tho, the other one was a little bit simplier... But your also worked, thanks a lot you too! :D